# Recursion for descending Fibonacci numbers

Tags: c, recursion, fibonacci

I've difficulties understanding recursion for descending Fibonacci numbers, tried to evaluate it by hand but with no success.

When evaluating the code I thought it would start with the following:
(5, 1, 2)

However, it starts with:
(1, 8, 13)
(2, 5, 8) and so on

I am completely lost here. Can somebody explain why does it work like that?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void fib_dec_a ( int n, int f1, int f2 ) {
    if ( n > 1 ){
        fib_dec_a ( n - 1, f2, f1 + f2 );
    }
    printf ("%d\n", f1);
}

int main () {
     int n;
     printf ( "Enter the length of descending Fibonacci sequence: " );
     scanf ( "%d", &n);
     printf ( "\nDescending sequence starting with an n-th element %d :\n", n );
     fib_dec_a (n, 1, 1 );
     return 0;
}
```

For n=6:
8
5
3
2
1
1

Comment: Do you have a specific question about this code?

Comment: Yes, I do not understand how the recursion works in the above example. I thought it would begin with (5, 1, 2) but it does not, and seems to start with (1, 8, 13).

Comment: Please update your question to reflect this in more detail, otherwise it'll get closed with something like "unclear what you're asking"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fib_dec_a` is a blocking call; execution will only continue after that function finishes whatever instructions it has to execute. As a result, in order to reach the `n == 1` case, the `n == 2` case must be completed first. The same then applies to the `n == 3` case; the `n == 4` case must finished executing first.

As a result of this, all the `printf` statements for lower values of `n` will be executed first, as their callee (`n + 1`) is waiting for this to return before executing. If you move the `printf` statement above the `if (n > 1)` branch, you'll find that the order is reversed.

Answer (score 0):

Until n>1 these functions are called recursively;
`f(6,1,1) -> f(5,1,2) -> f(4,2,3) -> f(3,3,5) -> f(2,5,8) -> f(1,8,13`)

`for f(1,8,13) => f1 = 8`

Then all functions in the reverse way completes the logging command run, 8, 5, 3, 2, 1, 1.